# Scrivener: Can I set spacing below the header?

Tags: style, screenwriting, scrivener

Can I set it so that there is a certain amount of space between the text on each page and the header?

Answer (score 1):

1. In Compilation Options, choose Formatting.
2. Select your Section Type you wish to modify, then choose "Set the line spacing" → Other.

   [image]
3. Increase Paragraph spacing after.

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to increase the height of your header. Alternately you could drag down your top margin on the main part of the page. I haven't used Scrivener so I couldn't tell you exactly how to do it.

Comment: Scrivener is not your usual word processor. These functionalities don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking about the header you can configure under "Headers and footers" in the "Page Settings" part of the format configuration. I.e. the small text that appears on the top of all or some pages.

The distance between the header text and the body text seems to be determined by the size of the top margin.

You can configure the top margin in the same place ("Margins" on the "Page Settings" pane).

I had to experiment with different top margins to get it right.

I assume the same goes for the footer text (e.g. page number).